# Set variables from a xml with spaces on a batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have many xml files like this:

```
<user_metadata>
  <user_id>141</user_id>
  <user_name>Julios Triton X (ssg)</user_name>
  <status>03</status>
  <user_level>4</user_level>
  <logins>41</logins>
  <time_online>207</time_online>
  <location>Dungeon 17,21,11</location>
  <avatar>URL</avatar>
  <class>1</class>
</user_metadata>
```

and I use a batch file to set some variables from the xml data, but I have a problems when the string have a space, this is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:data:
for %%a in (*.xml) do (
set "id="
set "name="
set "location="
set "time="

for /f "tokens=2 delims=>< " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i "<user_id>" ' ) do set id=%%b
for /f "tokens=2 delims=>< " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i "<user_name>" ' ) do set name=%%b
for /f "tokens=2 delims=>< " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i "<location>" ' ) do set location=%%b
for /f "tokens=2 delims=>< " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i "<time_online>" ' ) do set time=%%b
)
echo %id%
echo %name%
echo %location%
echo %time%
pause
```

Then I get this result:

```
141
Julios
Dungeon
207
```

On strings with spaces like "`<user_name>Julios Triton X (ssg)</user_name>`" only get the first value before the space (Julios) but I want all the string (Julios Triton X (ssg)), same on the string `<location>Dungeon 17,21,11</location>`.

How can set the full string as a variable?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "vars=user_id user_name location time_online"
FOR %%v IN (%vars%) DO SET "%%v="
FOR /f "tokens=2,3delims=<>" %%a IN (q24337603.txt) DO (
 FOR %%v IN (%vars%) DO IF "%%a"=="%%v" SET "%%v=%%b"
)
FOR %%v IN (%vars%) DO SET %%v

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a relatively easy way to do it. I've changed the variable names for convenience.

I used a file named `q24337603.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Results:

```
user_id=141
user_name=Julios Triton X (ssg)
location=Dungeon 17,21,11
time_online=207
```

Comment: Thanks works fine, but now I have a problema with some old xml who looks like this:

<data><user id='16' name='milller girl' location='Castle 4,0,17' time='66' status='4' class='2'/><user id='18' name='Dorothy88' location='Castle 0,2,1' time='10' status='0' class='0'/><user id='122' name='Shadow texll' location='Coast 321,882,425' time='104' status='5' class='9'/></data>

I can't define any varible.
is possible to generate multiple variables?

Comment: Can't tell where the new lines are. How about asking a new question. Thery're not *that* expensive!